# What kind of probability distribution is this?

Tags: probability, statistics

Not sure what kind of probability distribution deals with summation of results:

"A fair dice is thrown repeatedly until the sum of throws exceeds 6. Let the random variable X be the number of throws needed to obtain this. Find the probability mass function of X."

So far, I'm thinking that this might be a geometric distribution basing it on the unfixed number of trails needed to obtain the first success (sum = 6), yet I might be wrong. It starts getting confusing for me when I look at the possible probabilities of X.

Comment: It's certainly not a geometric distribution. A geometric distribution has possible values $1, 2, 3,...$ going on forever. Your distribution has possible values $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has a name.
X is a discrete random variable that can take the values in {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}.
I think you just have to find $P[X=x]$ for each of these $x$.

These might help:
i) for $x>2$, $P[X=x]=P[X\le x]-P[X\le x-1]$
ii) the probability $X\le x$ is the probability that the sum of the rolls on $x$ die are greater than 6.